# replace data in a column after some characters in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with values like:

```
1492966EMAIL1ABCDEFGHIJK12/22/2012 04:20:35
```

I want to replace the whole part after EMAIL1 in the column and this has to be done for more than 500000 rows. The problem is that the number of digits before EMAIL1 is not common in all the rows, but the value EMAIL1 is there in all the rows. I am not able to find the right function to go about this as I have tried using substr and trim, but I am not able to get the right query for this.

Can someone please tell me how this can be achieved in Oracle SQL? Let me know if more details are needed on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can use the functions `REPLACE()`, `SUBSTR()` and, `INSTR()` in the following:

```
select 
  replace(yourcol, substr(yourcol, instr(yourcol, 'EMAIL1')+6), '') newCol
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a0a/9)

Your final value will be:

```
|        NEWCOL |
-----------------
| 1492966EMAIL1 |
```

Then if you were to use this in a `UPDATE` statement, the query would be:

```
update yourtable
  set yourcol = replace(yourcol, substr(yourcol, instr(yourcol, 'EMAIL1')+6), '');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a0a/10)

Comment: this kind of looks fine..but its giving me the part before the EMAIL1...is it possible to get (and replace) the part after EMAIL1 as i want the data till EMAIL1 to be intact..only the part after that needs to be changed

Comment: @Sid if it is giving you the part before the `EMAIL1`, then you can easily replace it by changing the empty string to what you want -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a0a/14 In my original answer, I was just replacing the stuff after with an empty string

Comment: yes..it looks fine i guess..i will replace the empty string with the data i want..just confirming if the update statement given by you would work or not?

Comment: @Sid yes the update statement will work, just replace the empty string with the value you want

Comment: i will try this out and get back to u..as its a huge table, the update would take some time

Comment: If you are unsure on the `UPDATE`, you can always run this as the `SELECT` first to be sure the data is correct.

Comment: i know..the select is returning exactly the data that i need if i replace the empty string by the string i want..!!but since the update will be running long on a huge table, i had my doubts..but i m going to execute it shortly as i have backed up the table..:)

Answer (score 1):

This will exactly do your purpose,

```
Select SUBSTR(val,1,instr(val,'EMAIL1')+5) from table1
```

[fiddle_demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c3c6/6)

Get the string after 'EMAIL1' and replace it required string,

```
Select replace(SUBSTR(val,instr(val,'EMAIL1')+5),
'String you want to replace','string that replaces')
from table1
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c3c6/15)

```
update table1 set val=(Select replace(SUBSTR(val,instr(val,'EMAIL1')+5),
'String you want to replace','string that replaces') from table1)
where lower(val) like '%email1%';
```

[update_demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c3c6/18)

Comment: This method is simple and easy :)

Comment: can u pls explain this to me..difference between 'column' and 'my column'..??

Comment: what 'column' and 'my column' are you referring to? They are just examples. Did you see my fiddle_demo link, there I have demonstrated your requirement. Pls ask for more help :)

Comment: uh..the query looks fine..but i dont want the data before EMAIL1..i want the data after that to be replaced by something else..

Comment: Actually '+5' is enough. Because instr function will take you to position of 'E' in 'EMAIL1'.

Comment: yes..but i want to keep the 1 also..i want to replace the stuff after EMAIL1

Comment: it should be +6 only as i want to retain the 1 after EMAIl..the query looks fine, but i need an update query for the same

Comment: @Sid can you try my updated answer. Included update statement for your requirement. If it doesnt work then get back to me.

Comment: it looks fine..but i have already executed the query provided by bluefeet below..its executing now..thanks for the help though..!!

Comment: ok @Sid. If you found my answers as useful one, please vote it up. It will help me

Answer (score 1):

i hope your requirement is to concatenate a string after email1..for this sub-string position till email1 and concatenation with your required string ..

```
select SUBSTR(column_name,1,INSTR(column_name,'EMAIL1')+5)||'string' from table1
```

Comment: thank u..the query is almost similar to the one i used above provided by bluefeet..

Answer (score 0):

- Use **`INSTR`** function to find position of occurence of string ***EMAIL1*** .
- Select substring starting from beginning of original string upto
  starting position of ***EMAIL1*** plus 6 characters . 6 is length of *EMAIL1* substring.

If you want to select in this manner do

```
SELECT substr( column_name, 1, instr(column_name,'EMAIL1')+6)
```

If you want to update column values

```
UPDATE <table>
SET column_name = substr( column_name, 1, instr(column_name,'EMAIL1')+6)
```

Comment: i tried that..thing is that wen i use instr, it gives me an error saying subquery returns more than one row:                            select substr ( column_name, (select instr(column_name, 'L1') + 2 from table_name))

Comment: There is no need of inner select...no select before instr..substr() function works on one value at a time , your inner select is returning many rows and hence the error

Comment: i dont want to change the column name..i want to change the data..ie the rows only!!

Comment: ofcourse ! thats what it will do..column_name stores the value in your table , its the values on which the function will work...